# Speech recognition and signal visualization simultaneously

Tags: stream, kinect, speech-recognition, data-visualization

I'm using Kinect + Microsoft.Speech for speech recognition.

To get the input audio stream one has to do the following

```
Stream kinectAudioStream = myKinect.AudioSource.Start();
```

and to start speech recognition

```
speechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream(kinectAudioStream, new   SpeechAudioFormatInfo(...));
speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

My target is to visualize the input signal in real-time (like a oscilloscope) and do speech recognition simultaneously .

I tried some things like add speech recognition to the Microsoft "[AudioBasics-WPF C# Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131039.aspx)" in multiple threads. It works but the latency is very very very bad. To much interruptions in speech recognition and visualization.

Is there a way to increase the performance? Has anyone an idea?

Comment: So what is the system load during the process. Are interruptions due to high system load or due to some other factor.

Comment: Also, when you say that the latency is very bad, just how bad is it?  1 second? 10 seconds?  What is your host platform?

Comment: I think the latency is about 1 second more in comparison to “normal“ speech recognition or visualization. Also I got trouble with quality of recognition. The software runs only on desktop systems. Is there a way to optimize multiple accesses on the same stream?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your best option is to drop down to the Kinect DMO and connect a [SmartTee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filter, but that requires that you write in C++, as the KinectAudioSource doesn't expose the filter itself.